# TextArea in .razor not refreshed, although binding to a string variable

Tags: c#, razor, mqtt

I created a razor page "logsubscriber.razor" in my .net core 3.1 project, on whitch there is a textarea to show published massages from mqtt. But the textarea won't automatically update, although the bound string "textAreaValue" is changed. I create a mousedown event for the textarea. Only after I click the textarea, it will update and show the text. Why? How can the textarea show its subscribed text automatically?

my code is following:

```
@page "/logsubscriber"
<textarea @bind="@textAreaValue" style="width:100%" @onmousedown="eventArgs => { ha(); }" rows="20" />
@using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt
@using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages
@using System.Text
@code {
string textAreaValue = "";
private MqttClient client;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    client = new MqttClient("localhost");
    client.Subscribe(new string[] { "DataTracking/ticketing" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });//"DataTracking/ticketing" is the topic
    client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += MqttMsgPublishReceived;
    client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    await base.OnInitializedAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
}

void MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    string ReceivedMessage = e.Topic +":" +  Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
    textAreaValue += ReceivedMessage + Environment.NewLine;
}

void ha()
{
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround:
The html part now is

```
<div @onclick="eventArgs => { ha(); }" id="logdiv">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="CallMouseClick()" />
     <textarea @bind="@textAreaValue" style="width:100%" rows="20" />
</div>
```

and add a javascript:

```
function CallMouseClick() 
{
     setInterval(function () { document.getElementById('logdiv').click(); }, 2500);
}
```

every 2.5 second the div is programmatically clicked to make the textarea refresh.

Does anyone know a perfect solution other than the workaround?